# Aggregate in django with duration field

Tags: python, sql, django, duration, timedelta

My model is:

```
class Mo(Model):
    dur = DurationField(default=timedelta(0))

    price_per_minute = FloatField(default=0.0)

    minutes_int = IntegerField(default=0)  # dublicates data from dur , only for test
```

Some test data:

```
for i in range(4):
    m = Mo(dur=timedelta(minutes=i),
           minutes_int=i,
           price_per_minute=10.0)
    m.save()
```

I want to multiply the `dur` by `price_per_minute` and find `Sum`:

```
r = Mo.objects.all().aggregate(res=Sum(F('dur')*F('price_per_minute')))
print(r['res']/(10e6 * 60))
```

but:

```
Invalid connector for timedelta: *.
```

Explanation: In database `DurationField` is stored as a simple BIGINT that contains micro-seconds, if I know how to obtain it in aggregate I will divide it by (10e6 * 60) and will have paid minutes.

If I use a simple `IntegerField` instead everything works:

```
r = Mo.objects.all().aggregate(res=Sum(F('minutes_int')*F('price_per_minute')))
print(r['res']/(10e6*60))
```

So I need some cast to integer in the aggregate, is it possible to convert duration to some extra field?

```
r = Mo.objects.all().extra({'mins_int': 'dur'}).aggregate(res=Sum(F('mins_int')*F('price_per_minute')))
print(r['res']),
```

but

```
Cannot resolve keyword 'mins_int' into field. Choices are: dur, id, minutes_int, price_per_minute
```

Comment: Thanks! I think your comment should be the answer. It works perfactly r = Mo.objects.all().aggregate(res=Sum(ExpressionWrapper(F('dur'), IntegerField())*F('price_per_minute')))    print(r['res'] /(60e6)),

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ExpressionWrapper(F('dur'), output_field=BigIntegerField())` to make Django treat `dur` as an integer value.

Comment: This answer would be much improved if you explained what the integer was.  I am left guessing that it is microseconds since the start of epoch, but needing more research with no clear place to look. It would be doubly improved if you included for bonus points how to convert the aggregated value then back into a duration value that can be rendered in a template in a humanised form.