# How can I convert the value of a DurationField to its number of microseconds/minutes in a QuerySet?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

Suppose I have two models: Computer and DailyUsage. DailyUsage has a DurationField named `usage_duration`. On a QuerySet of Computers, I want to annotate the average daily usage **in minutes**. Each additional minute the computer has been used on average per day, the computer's "importance" increases.

I have seen examples* of people using ExpressionWrapper to convert a DurationField to its BigIntegerField representation, but attempting this:

```
average_in_duration_annotated = Computer.objects.annotate(
    avg=Avg("daily_usages__usage_duration", filter=Q(daily_usages__date__gte=one_month_ago))
)

average_in_minutes_annotated = average_annotated.annotate(
    avg_in_minutes=ExpressionWrapper(F("avg"), output_field=BigIntegerField()) / Value(10e6 * 60)
)
```

... results in:

`{TypeError}int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'datetime.timedelta'` when the QuerySet is evaluated.

Another example that fails the same way:

```
Computer.objects.annotate(
    total_usage_microseconds=Sum("daily_usages__usage_duration", output_field=BigIntegerField())
)
```

How can I convert the value of a DurationField to its number of microseconds in a QuerySet?

* [Aggregate in django with duration field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33237819/aggregate-in-django-with-duration-field)

Answer (score 0):

Because I'm using postgres, I can use `Seconds` from [django-pg-utils](https://pypi.org/project/django-pg-utils/):

```
qs.annotate(
    avg_usage_minutes=Avg(
        Seconds(F("daily_usages__usage_duration")) / Value(60),
        filter=Q(daily_usages__date__gte=one_month_ago)
    )
)
```